# Layout: one column as wide as it needs, the other taking the remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I need a **two column layout**, like a table, where I don't know how much the columns are wide.

I need the right column to be as much wide as its content (no word wrapping), and the left column to take the remaining space, doing word wrapping if there is not space available.

The right column is ok, while the left div `mainInfos` goes on top of it if the content needs it.

I want the columns to be side by side. What can I do to reach this result?

The container has a fixed width. I'd like not to use jquery.

```css
#post {
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 400px;
 border: solid 1px;
}
#post .mainInfos {
 overflow: hidden;
}
#post .details {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="post">
 <div class="mainInfos">really really long content that should be wrapped and should be all at the left of "small content", on the same line</div>
 <div class="details">small content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As per the answer below, use Flexbox. If you've not come across it before. Other than the documentation (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a good resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *flexbox* for this:

1. Add `display: flex` to the container `post`
2. Add `white-space: nowrap` to the `details` to prevent it wrapping
3. Add `flex: 1` to the `mainInfos` to let it take the remaining space.

See demo below:

```css
#post {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
#post .mainInfos {
  flex: 1;
}
#post .details {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="post">
  <div class="mainInfos">really really long content that should be wrapped and should be all at the left of "small content", on the same line</div>
  <div class="details">small content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One alternative to flexbox that works in new and old browsers is to use `display:table-cell` on the inner divs:

```css
#post {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
#post > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
#post .details {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="post">
  <div class="mainInfos">really really long content that should be wrapped and should be all at the left of "small content", on the same line</div>
  <div class="details">small content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it correct to use display: inline-cell without a parent having display: table?

Comment: it the really long content is short,  "small content" is not right aligned

Comment: @cdarwin yes to your first question and you can change the display of the parent div to table and give the details div a text-align of right

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox, First remove the float: right on the right column. Add to parent element (#post) this,

```
display: flex
```

[Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the example. I think it will be help you.

```css
#post {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 400px;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 400px;
  flex: 0 0 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#post .mainInfos,
#post .details {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border: 1px solid #989898;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -moz-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="post">
            <div class="mainInfos">
                really really long content that should be wrapped and should be all at the left of "small content", on the same line
                <br />
                really really long content that should be wrapped and should be all at the left of "small content", on the same line
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                small content<br />
                small content<br />
                small content<br />
                small content<br />
                <br />
                really really long content that should be wrapped and should be all at the left of "small content", on the same line
            </div>
        </div>
```